# Pandas: find complex numbers in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, complex-numbers

I have a large dataframe `test`.
Calling a custom function, it raises this error:

```
TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'", 'occurred at index ir_mt_1y')
```

**How can I find the complex numbers in `test`?**

My attempt is something like

```
pd.api.types.is_complex_dtype(test)
```

which simply gives

```
False
```

Edit for additional info:

```
test['ir_mt_1y'].head().to_dict()

{0: 0.11141100978777804,
 1: 2.775837591360907,
 2: 3.7201836925385474,
 3: -1.8665959833285382,
 4: 3.8716614787099735}
```

and

```
test['ir_mt_1y'].dtypes

dtype('O')
```

and

```
test['ir_mt_1y'].astype(float)

TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Comment: `is_complex_dtype` operates on arrays, so maybe iterate through each column and look for a `True`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander no, actually. Also tried `pd.api.types.is_complex_dtype(test['ir_mt_1y'])` and still gives `False`

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Add a couple of rows from the dataframe you have, you can print `df.head().to_dict()` then add the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = [3,5,67,1,5,5]
x2 = ['f', 'f', 'g','f','j','k']
x3 = [(92.289+151.96j),(-118.52-342.43j),(-7.1735-76.487j),(-458.09-1565.6j),(-118.41-340.58j),(-118.52-342.43j)]
x4 = [2,2,2,1,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [x1, x2, x3, x4]).T
for value in df.columns.values:
    df[value].apply(type)
```

Output:

```
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'int'>
5    <class 'int'>
Name: 0, dtype: object
0    <class 'complex'>
1    <class 'complex'>
2    <class 'complex'>
3    <class 'complex'>
4    <class 'complex'>
5    <class 'complex'>
Name: 1, dtype: object
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'str'>
Name: 2, dtype: object
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'int'>
5    <class 'int'>
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Maybe you can use this and the following comparison:

```
>>> type((92.289+151.96j)) == complex
True
```

Comment: ok, near a solution with `sum([type(x) == complex for x in test['ir_mt_1y']])` = 3

Answer (score 0):

```
df_find_complex = pd.DataFrame(index=test.index)
for col in test.columns:
    df_find_complex[col] = [type(x) == complex for x in test[col]]
```

Now I can indirectly find the complex numbers in `test` from `df_find_complex`.

Since my final objective (out of the question) is to replace complex numbers with `NaN`, I can do kind of:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df_find_complex, np.nan, test), columns=test.columns)
```

and call my function on `test1`.